# Applescript / Java - Detecting microphone input sound level

Tags: java, applescript

After extensive searches I can't find any information on how to detect the microphone sound level input in mac OSX using either Applescript or Java.

The purpose of this is to write an automatic volume adjust script based on the sound level detected by the built in microphone.

I know that commercial solutions exist but I'm interested simply as an exercise.

Just in case people think I'm posting on here just to make a statement I'm informed that I should add something to which a question mark can be added or people won't understand that it's a question.

I am after some example code in either java or applescript to show how to detect the microphone input sound level. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Comment: Sorry I assumed that making the statement on here would be sufficient for people to realise that I was asking for assistance in the specific area of the problem

Comment: So what, **specifically** is your question?  I can think of 5 that might arise from those words.  Choose **one** and add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17900233/edit).  This is not a 'general information & tutoring' site, it is a Q&A site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
```

This is from a [MacScripter thread](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=12615) that will probably answer some more of your questions on this project as well.